# Data Provider Mismatch error in Selenium with TestNG and Java

Tags: java, selenium, testng, testng-dataprovider

Can you please suggest for the possible cause of the Data provider mismatch error which is coming in case of implementing Excel flow from Selenium Java.

```
org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException: 
Data provider mismatch
Method: CreateFlow([Parameter{index=0, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=1, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=2, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=3, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=4, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=5, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=6, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=7, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=8, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=9, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=10, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=11, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}])
Arguments: [(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) AakashAuto,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) Dummy,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) dummy,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) gmaAIL.COM,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) asdsad,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) sads,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) asd,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) asd,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) Dummy,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) Dummy,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) Dummy,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) asd]
    at org.testng.internal.reflect.DataProviderMethodMatcher.getConformingArguments(DataProviderMethodMatcher.java:45)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.injectParameters(Parameters.java:796)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:983)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

**Code which I am using to get the Data from Excel:**

```
    public static Object[][] TestData() {
Workbook workBook;
    Sheet sheet;           
File src = new File(FilePath);
        workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(src); 
sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);
            int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();
            int cellCount = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
            Object[][] data = new Object[rowCount][cellCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {[![enter image description here][1]][1]
                for (int j = 0; j < cellCount; j++) {
                    data[i][j] = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(j);
                }
            }
            return data;
        }
```

Method where I am calling this TestData:

```
@DataProvider
    public Object[][] getData() {
        Object[][] data = TestUtil.TestData();
        return data;
    }

@Test(dataProvider = "getData")
public void CreateFlow(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String email, String DOB,
                String MobileNumber, String HomeNumber, String PIN, String id, String secondID, String AccountID,
                String number) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    //Printing all these values inside this method
        }
```

Comment: Hi, Can you share here the other code where you pass those TestData() as an argument?

Comment: Basically It says type mismatch.

Comment: @KajalKundu Have added the rest of the code as well.

Comment: Call TestData method is looks fine. I can't see any problem here.Could please check your excel sheet whether all values are text format? I guess DOB and mobile number values are not in correct format.I might wrong.

Comment: @CRUZE where have you declared "sheet" variable?

Comment: @ferpel declared the same inside the method, edited the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
org.testng.internal.reflect.MethodMatcherException: 
Data provider mismatch
Method: CreateFlow([Parameter{index=0, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=1, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=2, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=3, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=4, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=5, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=6, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=7, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=8, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=9, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=10, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}, Parameter{index=11, type=java.lang.String, declaredAnnotations=[]}])
Arguments: [(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) AakashAuto,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) Dummy,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) dummy,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) gmaAIL.COM,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) asdsad,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) sads,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) asd,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) asd,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) Dummy,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) Dummy,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) Dummy,(org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell) asd]
    at org.testng.internal.reflect.DataProviderMethodMatcher.getConformingArguments(DataProviderMethodMatcher.java:45)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.injectParameters(Parameters.java:796)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:983)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
```

As per the above error, the `createFlow()` method is expecting the String as an argument but you are passing the `Cell` which is not acceptable.

Try the below modified code :

```
public static Object[][] TestData() {
    sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);
    int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    int cellCount = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
    Object[][] data = new Object[rowCount][cellCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cellCount; j++) {
            // Call 'getStringCellValue()' here instead of using just 'getCell()'
            data[i][j] = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(j).getStringCellValue().trim();
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

You need to call the `getStringCellValue()` method to get the String data.

**Update :**

You will get an exception, if you are trying to read Numeric data from the excel by using `getStringCellValue()`.

To avoid this exception, you can append `'` apostrophe symbol as prefix in the Numeric cell of the excel sheet.

Suppose you have some data like below format in the excel :

```
| Ali   |
| 123   |
| Puppy |
```

you can get `Ali`, `Puppy` values using `getStringCellValue()` but you can't get `123` because it is Number so try to append `'` before that `123` in the excel and press enter. It looks something like this and you won't get that error.

```
| Ali   |
| '123  |
| Puppy |
```

If you want to fetch the data irrespective of the data type that has provided from the excel and you don't want to append `'` then you need to do something like below :

```
public static Object[][] TestData() {
    sheet = book.getSheetAt(0);
    int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    int cellCount = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
    Object[][] data = new Object[rowCount][cellCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cellCount; j++) {
            switch (sheet.getRow(1).getCell(j).getCellType()) {
               case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                   // Call 'getNumericCellValue()' here instead of using just 'getCell()'
                   data[i][j] = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(j).getNumericCellValue();
                   break;
               case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                   // Call 'getStringCellValue()' here instead of using just 'getCell()'
                   data[i][j] = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(j).getStringCellValue().trim();
                   break;
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Import `Cell` from `import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;` package.

I hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks @Ali.....  Able to solve it by adding getStringCellValue() method. But I am using both numbers and strings in my excel, and by using getStringCellValue (), I am getting another exception of Integer String mismatch.

Comment: Yes, you will get that exception if you are trying to read number as a string from the excel sheet. I will update the code for handling that scenario in few minutes... As it resolves your issue, please do accept and up vote my answer if it works or helpful to you... Thank you

Comment: Hi, tried with the second approach getCellType(), and again getting the same DataMismatch error.

Comment: Yes, it will fail indeed. Check your `public void CreateFlow(String firstName, String lastName, String address, String email, String DOB,
                String MobileNumber, String HomeNumber, String PIN, String id, String secondID, String AccountID,
                String number) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    //Printing all these values inside this method
        }` method arguments because all are `String` types and there are no `Numeric` types here, that's why your script is failing. If you follow the first approach then you won't face this issue...

Comment: yup... got it...and i did some modifications in second approach also by using DataFormatter class...and it's working like a charm now... :-)
Thanks for you help and debugging... :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
@DataProvider(name = "yourDPname")
public Object[][] getData() {
    Object[][] data = TestUtil.TestData();
    return data;
}

@Test(dataProvider = "yourDPname")
public void CreateFlow(String firstName, String lastName, String address,
        String email, String DOB, String MobileNumber, String HomeNumber,
        String PIN, String id, String secondID, String AccountID, String number)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    //Printing all these values inside this method }
}
```

Maybe try to assign name to your data provider and replace the dataprovider name instead the method name.